# break expression in inline if - python

Tags: python, if-statement, inline

Greeting, why is

```
for number in content:
    if number != 237:
        print(number)
    else:
        break
```

working code, but

```
for number in content:
    print(number) if number != 237 else break
```

has an error: expected expression after the inline else?

Comment: That simply isn't valid syntax. You can't do it that way.

Comment: if, for example, `content` is a list, you can use `content.clear()` instead of `break` if you really want to do it inline, if it's not a list, another way to break out of the loop would be to use something like `locals().update({"content": []})`, but uhh, well, just don't do it inline

Answer (score 0):

this is invalid syntax, to put this into prospective, this is the correct usage of the inline if

```py
for i in range(5):
    foo = 5 if i == 1 else 4
```

in this code, foo will be assigned the value of 5 or 4, but what about the next code

```py
for i in range(5):
    foo = 5 if i == 1 else break
```

what will be the value of foo when this code executes ? break returns nothing, its a language statement, so this is invalid syntax.
and your code is exactly the same, it just doesn't store the result anywhere, it's still bound to the same syntax rules, and while print(number) actually returns an object in python 3 (a None is a python object), break doesn't.